# Third conditional rules. I believe I came across a mistake in an english teaching book

Tags: conditionals

I came across this sentence in "American English file 3" and I'm wondering if it's written incorrectly or if there's something I don't understand about the third conditional:

***"If I'd have known you had a problem, I'd have helped you."***

I believe the ***"have"*** in the **if clause** is redundant. Am I correct?

Comment: Here *I'd* means I would, **not** I had! But you should also be aware that "the third conditional" is not a real thing.

Comment: It depends on whether the __I'd__ in the _if-clause_ is "_I __would__ (have known)..._" or "_I __had__ (have known)..._". In some English dialects "_If I would have known, ..._" is acceptable usage. On the other hand, "_If I had have known, ..._" is ungrammatical. The "_have_" should be omitted.